# env: php: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, catalina, php

I Worked before on my MacBook Pro on php applications and it was work smoothly , after I upgrade it to Catalina, when i use `composer update` it gives me an error , after reading about it I found that I have to use `zsh` but it gives me the same problem ,

when i use `which php` =>  `/usr/local/bin/php`

and `php -v` =>`PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2020 03:23:39) ( NTS )`

and `file /usr/local/bin/php` => `/usr/local/bin/php: Mach-O executable i386`

I used to use `MAMP Version 5.1 (350)`

Comment: Can you run `file /usr/local/bin/php` and add the result to the question? Most probably you are using the 32bit version of some required component.

Comment: @nohillside i've update my question and yes i got before  `i386` but how can i change it ?

Comment: Upgrade `php` (or MAMP)?

Comment: `php -v` =>`PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2020 03:23:39) ( NTS )`  and i do install another Apache like BitNami mamp and its work fine in onother macBook with Catalina , but mine not .

Comment: I found my problem , i used to use `ampps apache` and after that I installed `MAMP` and `php` file in `/usr/local/bin/php` going to `Ampps` application not to `MAMP`